# What are your thinking about Yoda conditions in Swift IOS

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I just to know from experienced IOS Developers, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using the "yoda condition". As I am learning the swift language. I don't know much about this topic. I did not find any suitable answer. Any help would Highly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: honestly, Abuzar, it's irrelevant.   just write the "if" statement, in the way, that feels most comfortable in the algorithm at hand.

Comment: @Fattie Thank you very very much for your time. Have a nice day.

Comment: LOL no worries my friend @abuzarmanzoor

Comment: In Swift you *cannot* inadvertently write `if a = 1`, it does not compile. So there is no advantage of using Yoda conditions (if there ever was one).

Comment: "opinion based" ?  how silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of a "Yoda condition" is nonsensical, because:

- the putative idea of "Yoda" style is: the two sides of the "==" operator, are reversed *"from what the usually would be"*...

However, that is nonsensical.

Because

- there is ***no sense at all*** of what they "usually would be".

It's a fairly dumb piece of "made-up" lingo.

Programmers write the if condition,

simply depending on,

what feels best to ***express the algorithm at hand***.

Forget about it.

At best, **it is of historic interest as a curiosity**, irrelevant to anyone young enough to be alive today.  To any new programmers learning (such as the OP here), it's irrelevant.

In the sense of the OP's question, it is irrelevant: there is **no right or wrong order.**

At best it's a matter of style to express the idea of the algorithm at hand.

Comment: Got the point. Thank you very much for you time.

Comment: The unhelpful rantings of a curmudgeon, entirely unhelpful and unkind.

Comment: This is just a rant, it doesn't explain why one should or should not use Yoda conditions.

Answer (score 4):

C, C++, Objective-C, and Java (and some other languages) have three properties that work together in an error-prone way:

1. Assignment is an expression. That is, `x = 1` is an **expression** with a value (the value 1 in this example).
2. Conditionals in control flow statements (like `if` and `while` statements) allow any expression that can be coerced to a Boolean value. Integers, floating point numbers, and pointers can all be coerced to Boolean: zero or null means false and anything else means true.
3. The assignment operator `=` and the equality operator `==` are very similar.

Because of these three features, it is easy to accidentally write `if (x = 1)` when you meant to write `if (x == 1)`. Your program still compiles, but probably behaves incorrectly some of the time.

The “Yoda conditional” is a style that helps prevent this error. If you are in the habit of writing `if (1 == x)`, and you accidentally write `if (1 = x)`, your program will not compile.

However, the `if (x = 1)` error cannot happen in Swift, because Swift lacks two of the three properties described above.

1. In Swift, an assignment like `x = 1` is a **statement**, not an **expression**. It cannot be used as the conditional of a control statement.
2. In Swift, the conditional of a control statement must explicitly be a `Bool`. No other types are automatically coerced to `Bool`. Even if assigment were an expression, `if (x = 1)` would still be prohibited because `x = 1` would have the type of `x`, which cannot be `Bool` because 1 is not a `Bool` value.

So there is no reason to ever use a Yoda condition in Swift (unless you find it clearer for some other reason).

Note also that many modern compilers for other languages will print a warning if you use an assignment as a conditional, so Yoda syntax isn't as useful as it used to be in C, C++, and Objective-C.

Comment: I got the point.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on what others have already said, yoda conditions are a holdover from C because of a specific bug that is easy to make in C and impossible in Swift. The bug in question goes like this:

```
if (x = 5) { ... }
```

The problem is that `x = 5` is an assignment. You *probably* meant `x == 5`. In C, assignment statements return the value, so `x = 5` returns 5, which is not 0, so it's true no matter what `x` is. This was a really common bug until compilers finally started to warn you about it. C actually relies on this, so it's not something C could remove. It's very common to use this in code like:

```
if (ch = getchar()) { ... }
```

The fix to this bug was to invert the condition by habit. `if (5 = x) { ... }` is a syntax error because 5 is a literal.

This is all irrelevant in Swift. Swift made `=` a statement rather than an expression, specifically to avoid this kind of bug. So `if x = 5 { ...}` is a syntax error already.

Yoda style just makes things harder to read; don't use it in Swift. Even in C, the compiler will give you stern warnings about this bug, so unless you are working in an old code base where it is the style, there's no reason to use it even there.

I'm not an experienced PHP programmer, where I believe it is also common. There it may still make sense. But not in Swift.

Comment: very informative. I got the point. Have a nice day.